# Bad margins while printing

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, geometry

I'm using `geometry` package like this:

```
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\newgeometry{twocolumn, left=0.25cm, right=0.25cm, top=0.8cm, bottom=0.4cm}
```

and `fancyhdr` package like this:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\bf{Some text}}
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyheadoffset[L]{0.42cm}
\fancyheadoffset[R]{-0.26cm}
```

And everything with margins is ok. But when I'm printing pdf on paper all margins is changing. How can I fix page margins for printing?

All code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}

\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[L]{\bf{Some text}}

\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}

\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\fancyheadoffset[L]{0.42cm}

\fancyheadoffset[R]{-0.26cm}

\setlength{\headsep}{0.2cm}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}

\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}

\definecolor{myviolet}{rgb}{0.5,0,0.36}

\lstset{
backgroundcolor=\color{white},
language=C++,
keywordstyle=\color{myviolet},
commentstyle=\color{mygreen},
frame=single,
framerule=0.1pt,
rulecolor=\color{black},
breakatwhitespace=true,
breaklines=true,
numbers=left,
stepnumber=1,
numbersep=5pt,
numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray},
showspaces=false,
showstringspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
tabsize=2,
framexleftmargin=10pt,
framexrightmargin=-10pt,

}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{russian}

\newgeometry{twocolumn, left=0.7cm, right=0cm, top=0.8cm, bottom=0.4cm}

\begin{lstlisting}
/* bfdlink.h -- header file for BFD link routines
   Copyright 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002,
   2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011
   Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   Written by Steve Chamberlain and Ian Lance Taylor, Cygnus Support.

   This file is part of BFD, the Binary File Descriptor library.

   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
   (at your option) any later version.

   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
   GNU General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
   along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
   Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street - Fifth Floor, Boston,
   MA 02110-1301, USA.  */

#ifndef BFDLINK_H
#define BFDLINK_H

/* Which symbols to strip during a link.  */
enum bfd_link_strip
{
  strip_none,       /* Don't strip any symbols.  */
  strip_debugger,   /* Strip debugging symbols.  */
  strip_some,       /* keep_hash is the list of symbols to keep.  */
  strip_all     /* Strip all symbols.  */
};

/* Which local symbols to discard during a link.  This is irrelevant
   if strip_all is used.  */
enum bfd_link_discard
{
  discard_sec_merge,    /* Discard local temporary symbols in SEC_MERGE
               sections.  */
  discard_none,     /* Don't discard any locals.  */
  discard_l,        /* Discard local temporary symbols.  */
  discard_all       /* Discard all locals.  */
};

/* Describes the type of hash table entry structure being used.
   Different hash table structure have different fields and so
   support different linking features.  */
enum bfd_link_hash_table_type
  {
    bfd_link_generic_hash_table,
    bfd_link_elf_hash_table
  };

/* These are the possible types of an entry in the BFD link hash
   table.  */

enum bfd_link_hash_type
{
  bfd_link_hash_new,        /* Symbol is new.  */
  bfd_link_hash_undefined,  /* Symbol seen before, but undefined.  */
  bfd_link_hash_undefweak,  /* Symbol is weak and undefined.  */
  bfd_link_hash_defined,    /* Symbol is defined.  */
  bfd_link_hash_defweak,    /* Symbol is weak and defined.  */
  bfd_link_hash_common,     /* Symbol is common.  */
  bfd_link_hash_indirect,   /* Symbol is an indirect link.  */
  bfd_link_hash_warning     /* Like indirect, but warn if referenced.  */
};

enum bfd_link_common_skip_ar_symbols
{
  bfd_link_common_skip_none,
  bfd_link_common_skip_text,
  bfd_link_common_skip_data,
  bfd_link_common_skip_all
};

struct bfd_link_hash_common_entry
  {
    unsigned int alignment_power;   /* Alignment.  */
    asection *section;      /* Symbol section.  */
  };

/* The linking routines use a hash table which uses this structure for
   its elements.  */

struct bfd_link_hash_entry
{
  /* Base hash table entry structure.  */
  struct bfd_hash_entry root;

  /* Type of this entry.  */
  ENUM_BITFIELD (bfd_link_hash_type) type : 8;

  unsigned int non_ir_ref : 1;

  /* A union of information depending upon the type.  */
  union
    {
      /* Nothing is kept for bfd_hash_new.  */
      /* bfd_link_hash_undefined, bfd_link_hash_undefweak.  */
      struct
    {
      /* Undefined and common symbols are kept in a linked list through
         this field.  This field is present in all of the union element
         so that we don't need to remove entries from the list when we
         change their type.  Removing entries would either require the
         list to be doubly linked, which would waste more memory, or
         require a traversal.  When an undefined or common symbol is
         created, it should be added to this list, the head of which is in
         the link hash table itself.  As symbols are defined, they need
         not be removed from the list; anything which reads the list must
         doublecheck the symbol type.

         Weak symbols are not kept on this list.

         Defined and defweak symbols use this field as a reference marker.
         If the field is not NULL, or this structure is the tail of the

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Command line for compiling:

latex a.tex
dvipdfm a.dvi

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: I've added MWE.

Answer (score 6):

Possible reasons:

### Acrobat Reader/Shrink to printable area

Options for printing with Acrobat Reader are (naming can vary):

1. None
2. Fit to page area
3. Shrink to printable area

The default is (3) that means, the page is scaled down to fit the printable
area if needed. Option (2) can also scale the page up. You need "None" to
avoid scaling.

### Wrong paper size

Some TeX distributions can be configured for default paper sizes.
But that does not change the default for the standard classes.
Without paper size option, the standard classes uses `letterpaper`.
Then the margins are not correct on an A4 paper, if they are set
for letter size.

Remark: LaTeX and the standard classes do not tell the driver the
correct paper size. The latter is done by packages such as `geometry`,
`hyperref`, some `pdftex.def` (driver for `graphics`/`color`), …
Without such a package and a paper size option, the result can be a
PDF document with paper size A4 (TeX distribution/driver default),
but at LaTeX level the page layout inclusive margins are configured for
letter paper size.

**Update**: The used class is `extarticle`, its default is *letter* paper, thus option `a4paper` is needed:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{extarticle}
```

Comment: I'll try first option.
My code (I've added it in question) starts with
    \documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}.

Comment: I have tried None(Actual size) option but it don't help.

Comment: @Edvard You can edit your question to add a complete, but minimal example file, tell the used and wanted paper sizes, and which PDF viewer you are using.

Comment: I've added complete example. I am using A4 paper size. Of course I want to print in landscape mode. I'm using Adobe Reader X v 10.1.6 on Windows 7.

Comment: @Edvard Answer updated for class `extartcle` and A4 paper size.

Comment: Now if I'm printing with Actual size option header is disappearing. If I'm printing with Fit option left margin became very large. Right margin is greater than in pdf. Top and bottom margins with Fit option is ok.

Comment: @Edvard The example is far from minimal. It contains several `\newgeometry` settings along with lower level settings (`\headsep`). What is the difficulty to make a simple one page document with the `geometry` settings for your page layout?